# DC.JS Filtering Scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

So i'm not sure if the scatterplot is part of the stable version yet. I am currently working with a medium-large data set (600k rows, three columns).

I currently have three line charts, one for each column variable, and when I filter on one the others respond quickly and easily which makes Dc.js so great!

However, I am also trying a scatterplot (x and y are two of the coulmns (one each)), and when I filter the first line chart the scatterplot is very slow to update (maybe a minute or two?).

Is this expected, or maybe I have unreasonable expectations for the scatterplot?

Thanks. Cheers

Comment: I think that displaying 600K points, if that's what you're doing, is going to be outside what d3 can handle - at least with the DOM, and dc.js does not support drawing to the canvas.  It's not about the amount of data but the number of graphical objects.  Now, if your data is reduced and you only have 100s or 1000s of points displayed, I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: hmmm i'll think about ways to aggregate it. thanks for the insight!